# use keyboard to move div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Alright, so I'm trying to make a simple script that moves down a div when I press 's' but it's not firing at all. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

http://prime.programming-designs.com/designs/map/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$ is not defined
http://prime.programming-designs.com/designs/map/
Line 28`
Have you included jQuery or Prototype BEFORE your own script?

Comment: He hasn't included any script anywhere.  Download jQuery from http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery and include it.  Alternately, use it from google: `<script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script><script>google.load('jquery', '1.3.1');</script>`

Comment: Alright, that fixed that, but now I'm getting unexpected token in attribute selector '!' and no line.

Comment: Wait, it says it's a warning, not a error. But my script still isn't working. Can you check it out again and tell me what I did wrong?